# TortoiseSVN - Ignoring files within a folder already in the repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

How do I ignore all files within a folder under source control?

`/project/published/` is a folder I want to keep

`/project/published/some_file(s)` are files/folders I don't want

More Details: Currently when I go to commit changes for my project I see a lot of files that I don't want to. They are files that get published to a folder and I don't need them under source control. I won't ever know the names of these files as they are chosen by users.

I tried to use the property `svn:ignore` with value `published/*` but that did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 56):

You just right click on the `published/` folder, select TortoiseSVN -> Properties, click New -> Advanced with the following:

- Property name: `svn:ignore`
- Property value: `*`

Then it would work fine.

Comment: On the latest TortoiseSVN you would have to go to TortoiseSVN -> Properties -> New... -> Other

Comment: What if you had multiple projects with the same structure and you wanted some_files(s) ignored in every one?

Answer (score 12):

I've found a solution. If I set the svn:ignore property directly on the folder I want to keep (published) and set it's value to * then it does what I want. I would have liked to add this property to the project root but this works too.

prop - svn:ignore

value - *

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this can help you: in the Commit dialog there's a check box to "Show unversioned files". It's not the same as telling Tortoise/SVN to ignore them but might just do the trick. HTH

Comment: I've been using that approach and it's been a hassle. If I have that unchecked I sometimes neglect to add new files to source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you tried:

```
svn propset svn:ignore published/*
```

`svn propset` needs the value and target seperated:

```
svn propset svn:ignore [value] [target]
```

...so try:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" published
```

(Don't forget the quotes.)

Comment: Your suggestion let me to apply the property directly to the folder as I wasn't using the command line to set the property but using TortoiseSVN's UI instead.